# learning require with javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs

trying to learn require.js - I have a main with require loading a simple function to retrieve the browser window size. I am getting the Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object] http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch error.

here is both main.js and helper\getwindowsize.js - I don't know what I am doing wrong.

main.js

```
//determine how much space is available within the browser window
var viewportWidth;
var viewportHeight;

require(["helper/getwindowsize"], function(GetBrowserWindowSize) { getwindowsize.GetBrowserWindowSize(); });

GetBrowserWindowSize(viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportWidth+'x'+viewportHeight+'</p>');
```

helper\getwindowsize.js

```
define(function() 
{
  console.log("Function : GetBrowserWindowSize");

  return 
  {
    GetBrowserWindowSize: function(viewportWidth, viewportHeight)
    {
      // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight 
      if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
      {
        viewportWidth = window.innerWidth, viewportHeight = window.innerHeight
      }

      // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
      else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
               'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
      {
        viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth, viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
      }

      // older versions of IE 
      else
      {
        viewportWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth, viewportHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the error you reported. There were, however, quite a few other problems, most of which were not RequireJS issues:

1. Your `getwindowsize.js` file had a syntax error.
2. You tried to return values by modifying the parameters passed to `GetBrowserWindowSize`. JavaScript is a pass-by-value language. If you do:

   ```
   function foo(a) {
       a = ... something else ...;
   }

   var x = ... something ...;
   foo(x);
   ```

   `x` will still evaluate to what it was before the call to `foo`. The proper way to do what you want is to return an object with the fields set to the values you want to return.
3. In `main.js` you were trying to call `GetBrowserWindowSize` without properly going through your module.
4. [This is the only RequireJS issue that was in your code.] In `main.js` you had code that depends on your module being properly loaded that was *outside* the callback passed to `require`. This is flat out wrong. One of the basic rules of RequireJS: **everything** that depends on a module being loaded must be *executed from inside* the callback passed to the `require` or `define` function that requires the module.

Here are versions of your files that do work fine. (Disclaimer: I did not evaluate the validity of the logic used to get the viewport size.) `main.js`:

```
require(["helper/getwindowsize"], function(getwindowsize) {
    //determine how much space is available within the browser window
    var size = getwindowsize.GetBrowserWindowSize();
    document.write('<p>Your viewport width is ' + size.viewportWidth +
                   'x' + size.viewportHeight+'</p>');
});
```

`helper/getwindowsize.js`:

```
define(function() {
    console.log("Function : GetBrowserWindowSize");

    return {
        GetBrowserWindowSize: function () {
        // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
            if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
                return {
                    viewportWidth: window.innerWidth,
                    viewportHeight: window.innerHeight
                };
            }
            // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
            else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' &&
                     typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' &&
                   document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
              return {
                  viewportWidth: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                  viewportHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight
              };
          }
            // older versions of IE
            else {
                return {
                    viewportWidth: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
                    viewportHeight: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
                };
            }
        }
    };
});
```

When you try these files, make sure that your cache does not interfere with loading the new version.

Edited to add. Here's the `index.html` file I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the only files you need:

```
./main.js
./helper/getwindowsize.js
./index.html
./js/require.js
```

You get `require.js` from [RequireJS's site](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: hrmmm.. now I have 2 errors.. still getting the regular http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch error in addition to a getwindowsize is not defined, I simplified both scripts just to see if I can get anything to work, and still fails

Comment: `main.js` `require(["helper/getwindowsize"], function(GetBrowserWindowSize)
        {
          var size = new GetBrowserWindowSize();
          console.log(size);
        });`

Comment: `getwindowsize.js` `define(function() 
{
    return 
    {
      GetBrowserWindowSize: function()
      {
              var size= 100;
             return size;
      }
    }
});`

Comment: Updated my answer to list the ``index.html`` and all the files I use. Please replicate on your side with the additional information.